# CLT for Bernoulli Random Variables; Understanding Derivation of Formula

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, self-study

I am trying to understand the $\chi^2$ - test and I have difficulties understanding the following part from it's derivation (from Introduction to Mathematical Statistics Hogg, Chapter 4):

Definition CLT: $ Z_n = \frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \approx N(0,1)$, ok no problem here.

Now: Let $X_1 \text{ be } b(n, p)$ consider the following RV:

$$Y_1 = \frac{X_1-np}{\sqrt(np(1-p)}, \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty, Y \approx N(0,1)$$ according to the CLT.

As such it is stated in the book. However, from the Binomial distrubution: $\text{expected value } (\mu) = np \text{ and the variance } (\sigma^2) = np(1-p)$, which can be derived from it's MGF.

Here is my problem: according the CLT formula there should be a devision of $\sqrt{n}$:

$$Y_1 = \frac{X_1-np}{\sqrt(np_1(1-p) / \sqrt{n}}, \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty, Y \approx N(0,1)$$

No matter how you look at it, there is a $\sqrt{n}$ in $Y_1$ missing.

Comment: $\sigma$ refers to the standard deviation of $X$ in the CLT formulat, not $\bar{X}$...

Comment: You don't explicitly get to the chi-squared part in your question (even though it's in your text). So I changed the title better searching. // Welcome. Please take the 'tour' of our site to take full advantage of how it works.

Comment: If you disagree with my edits, feel free to reverse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment:** This should get you started, if you pay attention to my notation, which may differ from yours. Make necessary adjustments, fill in any gaps, and continue.

Let $B_i \sim \mathsf{Bern}(p),$ with $\mu = E(B_i) = p$ and $\sigma = SD(B_i) = \sqrt{pq}.$

Also, $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n B_i \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n,p)$
and $\bar X = \frac{1}{n}S_n,$ where $E(\bar X) = p\,,$ $Var(\bar X) = pq/n,\,$ $SD(\bar X) = \sqrt{pq/n}.$

So
$$Z = \frac{\bar X - p}{\sqrt{pq/n}}
= \frac{n\bar X - np}{\sqrt{npq}} = \frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{npq}}.$$